# Running query from inside Cloud Function using request parameters

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am having troubles running queries from Cloud Functions using the request parameters to build the query form HTTP calls. In the past, I have ran queries from cloud functions fine with no error. My problem arises when I try to run the query using parameters gotten from the request.

When I hardcode the location of the document in the function, it works fine but when I try to build a query, it returns status code of 200. I have also logged the the built query and it is logging out the right thing but no data is being returned. It only returns data when the document path is hardcoded. See code below.

```
Query looks like this
https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/getData/CollectionName/DocumentName

export const getData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const params = request.url.split("/");
    console.log("the params 0 "+params[0]);
    console.log("the params 1 "+params[1]);
    console.log("the params 2 "+params[2]);

    //Build up the document path
    const theQuery = "\'"+params[1]+"\/"+params[2]+"\'";
    console.log("the query "+theQuery); <-- logs out right result in the form 'Collection/Document'

    //Fetch the document
    const promise = admin.firestore().doc("\'"+params[1]+"\/"+params[2]+"\'").get() <---- This doesnt work, building the query

    //const promise = admin.firestore().doc('collectionName/DocID').get() <---- This hard coded and it works 

    promise.then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.data()
        response.send(data)

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        response.status(500).send(error);
    })

});
```

I tried using a different approach and giving the datafields a names as seen below

```
Query looks like this
https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/getData?CollectionName=CName&DocumentID=Dname


export const getData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
     const collectName = request.query.CollectionName;

    const DocId = request.query.DocumentName;

    //Build up the document path
    const theQuery = "'"+collectName+"\/"+collectName+"'";
    console.log("the query "+theQuery); <---Logs out correct result

    //Fetch the document
    const promise = admin.firestore().doc(theQuery).get() <-- Building the query does not work

//const promise = admin.firestore().doc('collectionName/DocID').get() <---- This hard coded and it works 

    promise.then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.data()
        response.send(data)

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        response.status(500).send(error);
    })

});
```

In both cases, when the request is build from the URL, it does not return any data and it does not return any errors. And I am sure the documents I am trying to fetch exsist in the database. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Why are you adding single quotes around `theQuery`? What purpose does that serve? That seems to be a problem to me.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `request.path`. Then you can obtain the path components, e.g. `request.path.split("/")[1]`

The syntax for `request.query` is valid when using **Express**. This is referenced in some of the docs, but not made explicit that Express is required. It's confusing.

To properly handle the dynamic inputs, you may have more luck working with Express and creating routes and handlers. This [Firebase page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) has links to some projects using it.

[Walkthough set-up](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions.html) using Express on Firebase.